# How to prevent recovering metadata when using ExifTool?

Tags: privacy, metadata, exiftool

When using `exiftool -all:all= file.pdf` this message appears:

> ExifTool PDF edits are reversible. Deleted tags may be recovered!

Can tag recovery be prevented when ExifTool is used? Can it just wipe/overwrite them without saving previous info?

PDF is an example. I know about MAT2 but I don't want to rebuild and rasterize files, as MAT2 does.

Comment: See this....https://dustri.org/b/cleaning-pdf-metadata-in-depth.html

Comment: @Moab I've updated the question.

Comment: I cannot find any way to do what you want without rebuilding the pdf. Let us know if you discover a way, thanks.

Comment: I found this but it is only for jpg metedata....http://www.linux-magazine.com/Online/Blogs/Productivity-Sauce/Remove-EXIF-Metadata-from-Photos-with-exiftool

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The author of exiftool looked into zeroing out the data in August 2019 and has decided that against it.

> 1. It is harder than I had hoped to simply zero out the existing metadata.
> 2. The solution wouldn't be complete because there could already be unused objects containing old metadata in the original PDF, and
>    ExifTool wouldn't be able to zero out these.
> 3. It has been advertised that ExifTool PDF edits are reversible, and some users may be relying on this feature.

See [this thread](https://exiftool.org/forum/index.php/topic,3943.msg54610.html#msg54610) on the exiftool forums.

The use of [qpdf](http://qpdf.sourceforge.net/) or similar programs to re-linearize after using exiftool is still how exiftool's author suggests to fully remove all metadata.

Comment: What does linearization do?

Comment: Linearizing a pdf reorganizes the data in a pdf so it is faster to read through the web.  It basically makes it more steamable, allowing the web browser to show the first page right away before the whole PDF is downloaded.  See the last paragraph under the [PDF->File Structure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PDF#File_structure) wikipedia page, just before "Imaging model".

Comment: It seems that it's a reasonably easy and fast method, which doesn't increase the filesize a lot.

Answer (score 4):

Following the [previous answer](https://superuser.com/a/1482629/400542), here is what is [suggested in the exiftool forum](https://exiftool.org/forum/index.php?topic=3943.msg54704#msg54704) to remove PDF metadata:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
# Strip metadata and re-linearise:
exiftool -all= -overwrite_original "$1"
mv "$1" /tmp/temp.pdf
qpdf --linearize /tmp/temp.pdf "$1"
```

Comment: Newer versions of `qpdf` can avoid the temporary file with the `--replace-input` option.